# Обновление информации на сайте без перезагруки

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Подскажите как с помощью ajax дополнить скрипт, который будет обновлять информацию каждую секунду на сайте без перезагрузки страницы

```
 <div id="content"></div>  

<script>  
    function show()  
    {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "time.php",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $("#content").html(html);  
            }  
        });  
    }  

    $(document).ready(function(){  
        show();  
        setInterval('show()',1000);  
    });  
</script>
```

Пробовал такой скрипт, но есть проблемы, из-за того, что он обновляется каждую секунду блок мерцает

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, только о тебе вспоминал с этим комментарием

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что если сервер вернёт ошибку или запрос будет выполняться дольше указанного времени? Лучше `setTimeout` в `success` или `done`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    show();
    var count = 0;

    function show() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'time.php',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                count++;
                $("#content").html(data + ' ' + count);
                setTimeout(function() {show();}, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Что мерцает?

```js
var counter = 0;

    function show()  
    {  
        counter++;
      
        $("#content").html(counter + " Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting \
industry. Lorem Ipsum \
has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and \
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into \
electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of \
Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus \
PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. " + counter);

        /*$.ajax({  
            url: "time.php",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $("#content").html(html);  
            }  
        });  */
    }  

    $(document).ready(function(){  
        show();  
        setInterval(show,1000);  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Вроде норм сейчас, походу что-то другое не работает.
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

современный подход - использование websocket. обновление возможно по инициативе сервера, т.е. есть изменение данных - сервер посылает на клиента.